# Parse error while rendering the pdf file in angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, pdf.js

When I try to access the pdf file which is public using the angular-pdf-viewer I got the following error message on console.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [http://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf] starting at [://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf].
```

here is my pdf directive for rendering the pdf file:

```
<pdf-viewer delegate-handle="my-pdf-container" url="http://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf" scale="1" show-toolbar="true" ></pdf-viewer>
```

could anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Can you share the directive's code ?

Comment: @mirfan899 is this solved for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the samples seems to be suggesting define url on scope and reference it. But you may try the following, which ***stringifys*** the url

```
<pdf-viewer delegate-handle="my-pdf-container" url="'http://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf'" scale="1" show-toolbar="true" ></pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Error gone but I've got more errors.

   `OPTIONS http://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf 403 (Forbidden)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf:1 OPTIONS http://pucdocket.s3.amazonaws.com/VA/PUE-2010-00039/122913.pdf 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: here is my app config: 

`app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
}
]);`

Comment: @mirfan899 I assume that the reason you see this error is CORS, since you are trying to retrieve a file outside your host, try using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ or create your own proxy